# String converts in num while csv to pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have weird behaviour while converting csv to dataframe. if cell has formatted as string. When cell contains "1,2,3" it treats as string, however when it is "1", it reads as a integer.

What could be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: can you provide a sample of the csv file (full rows, not just single "cell")?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the dtype of a column when reading a csv as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (check section converters)

Read a dataframe as follows:

`df = pandas.read_csv('whatever_csv_file.csv', converters={'name_of_column_with_integers': str})`